# Loot chest in Edgeville Stronghold of Player safety?

Tags: runescape

In Runescape where is the loot chest that has 10 thousand coins and fighter gloves? I looked everywhere but I can't find it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The loot chest is on the bottom floor of the SoPS. You have to toggle the lever before you can enter the iron jail cell gates. When you enter follow the hall until you reach a bend. Go around that bend to find the chest.

[image: Safety Chest]

<sup>*[Stronghold treasure chest.png](https://runescape.wiki/w/File:Stronghold_treasure_chest.png) from RuneScape Wiki, used under a [Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike license](https://meta.weirdgloop.org/w/Meta:Copyrights).*</sup>

Comment: That's it. It's in the jail cell?

Comment: Pretty much ya.

Comment: [If you're going to steal images, please cite them](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/File:Stronghold_treasure_chest.png).

Comment: @Haidro Hey, easy on the attacking.  Yeah, you got a point, but there's no reason to make it personal.  If plagiarism is happening, make sure to flag it.  We delete content that doesn't attribute properly.

Comment: the image was taken off of imgur.

Comment: @YoungGuilo That doesn't make any difference. Imgur doesn't magically give you a license to copy a picture.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I was giving it credit.

Comment: Did the image description say it was licensed for use under the condition that credit was given? If not, it's copyrighted and you cannot use it. You also haven't actually given correct credit if it was, since you do not mention the person who created it or the link to the original and its license.

Comment: "Image is free to use or share even commercially. Credit is not needed in order to post/share image." - Google Images Search caption.

Comment: @YoungGuilo [Okay, show me where GIS says that.](http://tinyurl.com/qj5mqwm) I'm dubious, given that the original image appears to be CC-BY-SA.

Comment: Whatever, this isn't a hard problem to fix and I don't know why you're resisting it. I did it for you.

Answer (score 3):

So firstly, the Stronghold of Player Safety is located north of Gunnarsgrunn (formerly known as Barbarian Village). On the west side of the house there is a jail entrance you can use to enter the building. Go into the second room on the left and pull back the poster. You will enter into a dungeon.

From here, run north, then around south, then up north again, until you see cockroach soldiers. Run to the north point and go up the stairs. Run west into a small room with three cockroach soldiers there. Pull the old lever in the room, then go back down the stairs.

NOTE: The monsters **are not** aggressive, so you are completely safe here (unless you attack them, and they can do some hefty damage)

After going down the stairs, you will see a jail door on the east side of the room. Go into it, and you will appear on another floor. Follow the path and then go north. You will see the chest on the right.

Open the chest... and:

[image: Hooray. Free rewards :D]

The antique lamps give 500xp in any skill, and the fighting gloves give an armour bonus of 7 and a life point boost of 15.

Comment: Why the downvote please